# ConEmuC: how to avoid: Root process was alive less than 10 sec

Tags: conemu

How can I avoid this message? I would like that if the process ends... then the console should close.

```
D:\Projects.sc\start cmdn

ConEmuC: Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode=0.
Press Enter or Esc to close console...
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer:

```
Settings->Integration->Default term->Confirm Close
```

See attached screenshot.

[image]